# iOS Application Settings Bundle constraints

Tags: ios, xamarin, constraints, settings, bundle

I'm using the Settings bundle for an iOS application. Is it possible to add some constraints to a field based on another field?

I give an example. I have two fields:

```
Field1: 10;  
Field2: 15;
```

**It is possible to force the user to put into 'Field2' a value that is smaller than 'Field1' ?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, validation logic like that can't be included in the settings bundle. It is a purely static/declarative form of defining the structure of the settings. However, you can of course validate and sanitize the properties at the point where you read them from `NSUserDefaults` in your app.